# Returning error from reactor Flux goes infinite

Tags: java, project-reactor, micronaut, reactor, micronaut-rest

I have updated the Micronaut application from 2.5.XX to 3.0.0. As per the Micronaut documentation, the project reactor is the recommended reactive library to use for reactive programming.

```
@Controller("/product")
public class ProductController implements IProductOperation {
    @Override
    public Flux<List> freeTextSearch(String text) {
        return iProductManager.findFreeText(text).onErrorResume(throwable -> {
            return Flux.error(new GlobalException(throwable));
        });
    }
}

public interface IProductOperation {
    @Get(value = "/search/{text}")
    Flux<?> freeTextSearch(@NotBlank String text);
}
```

When I CURL the end point `curl -X 'GET' 'http://localhost:8081/product/search/ffff' -H 'accept: application/json'` it goes to the infinite.

Since I have an error on the system so return `Flux.error(new GlobalException(throwable));` should return the 500 internal system error, however, it goes to the infinite

I have integrated rabbitMQ and rabbitMQ producer is shutdown. `iProductManager.findFreeText(text)` throws an exception since the rabbitMQ producer is not running. Instead of going infinite, it should throw an exception and global error handling should get called. But is is not working as expected

```
public class GlobalException extends RuntimeException{
    public GlobalException(Throwable throwable){super(throwable);}
}
```

This method never get called on error.

```
@Produces
@Singleton
@Requires(classes = {GlobalException.class, ExceptionHandler.class})
public class GlobalExceptionHandler implements ExceptionHandler<GlobalException, HttpResponse> {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GlobalExceptionHandler.class);

    @Override
    public HttpResponse handle(HttpRequest request, GlobalException exception) {
        LOG.error(exception.getLocalizedMessage());
        LOG.error(exception.getCause().getMessage());
        Arrays.stream(exception.getStackTrace()).forEach(item -> LOG.error(item.toString()));
        return HttpResponse.serverError(exception.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

**Logs**

```
22:40:02.151 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] INFO  reactor.Flux.OnErrorResume.1 - onSubscribe(FluxOnErrorResume.ResumeSubscriber)
22:40:02.176 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] INFO  reactor.Flux.OnErrorResume.1 - request(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using the wrong reactor `Flux` operator:

- `onErrorResume` switches to a different `Flux` in case of errors; you can consider that as a "fallback Flux". In your case, the fallback throws itself an error - this could explain the infinite loop.
- `onErrorMap` should do what you're looking for: mapping an exception to another that can be used for the HTTP response

If you'd like to wrap **all exceptions** from that Flux, you could do:

```java
return iProductManager.findFreeText(text)
        .onErrorMap(throwable -> new GlobalException(throwable));
```

Note that other `onErrorMap` methods allow you to have more fine-grained behavior.

Comment: No it is not working using onErrorMap same issues

Comment: then you should update your question with debug logs for Micronaut to figure out where the recursion happens. You can also add a `.log()` operator right after the `onErrorMap` to get more information.

Comment: Added the logs on the question, these logs are only available and loop application is on infinite

Comment: Why is it still using `OnErrorResume`? Did you switch to `onErrorMap`?

Comment: I am using this code  return iProductManager.findFreeText(text).onErrorMap(throwable -> new GlobalException(throwable)).log();

Comment: The handler method from GlobalExceptionHandler class never get called